# JavaScript: refactoring, avoiding array.push()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got a function in an object like this:

```
arrayofElements: function(item) {

    var result = [];

    if (item.isA) {
        result.push(new Div('aClass', labels['A']));
    }

    if (item.isC) {
        result.push(new Div('cClass', labels['C']));
    }

    if (item.isD) {
        result.push(new Div('dClass', labels['D']));
    }

    return result;
},
```

How can this be refactored? I dislike having to push() each item conditionally.

Comment: What other properties does `item` have?

Comment: Do you dislike the .push() method? or the conditions wrapping each call?

Comment: Is the labels property accessible from within an item object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could move the `is*` properties to a sub-object so as to isolate them, and loop over the sub-object's properties

```
item.is={A:'aClass', C:'cClass'};
...
arrayofElements: function(item) {
    var result = [];
    for (p in item.is) {
        result.push(new Div(item.is[p], labels[p]));
    }
    return result;
},
```

The values in `item.is` could be the classes (as shown), or the values in `item.is` could be objects with a `class` property, or you could use the property name `p` as an index in another object to get the classes. Which depends largely on what the `item`s represent and what the element classes are most closely associated with.

Answer (score 1):

```
arrayofElements: function(item) {

var result = [],
    items = ['A', 'C', 'D'];
while(var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if(item["is" + items[i]]) {
    result.push(new Div(items[i] + 'Class', labels[items[i]]))
  }
}
return result;
},
```

Remember that obj.foo is the same as obj['foo'] in Javascript

Answer (score 0):

A variant of Larry's solution:

```
arrayofElements: function(item) {
  var result = [], letters = ['A','C','D'], ltr, i, len;
  len = letters.length;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    ltr = letters[i];
    if (item["is"+ltr]) {
      result.push(new Div(ltr.toLowerCase()+"Class", labels[ltr]));
    }
  }
  return result;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This function avoids using push() and is functionally identical to yours:

```
arrayofElements: function(item) {

    if (item.isA) {
       return [new Div('aClass', labels['A'])];
    }

    if (item.isC) {
       return [new Div('cClass', labels['C'])];
    }

    if (item.isD) {
       return [new Div('dClass', labels['D'])];
    }

    return [];
},
```

Comment: not quite. In his code if item looks like `{isA:true,isC:true}` it will return `[new Div('aClass', labels['A']),new Div('cClass',labels['C'])]` Array#push modifies the array it is called on.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I assumed that an item could only be true for one of  isA, isC, or isD.